# Iterate through TabItems in a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, button, tabs, automation

I have a tabcontrol with 9 tabitems in it.  Each tab has as series of TextBoxes for the user to enter data.  At the bottom is a clear button, hooked up to this method:

```
public void ClearTextBoxes()
    {
        ChildControls ccChildren = new ChildControls();

        foreach (object o in ccChildren.GetChildren(rvraDockPanel, 2))
        {
            if (o.GetType() == typeof(WatermarkTextBox) || o.GetType() == typeof(DateBox) ||
                o.GetType() == typeof(DigitBox) || o.GetType() == typeof(PhoneBox))
            {
                WatermarkTextBox water = (WatermarkTextBox)o;
                water.Text = "";
            }
            else if (o.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
            {
                ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)o;
                combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            else if (o.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                CheckBox check = (CheckBox)o;
                check.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine, however I also have a MenuItem that allows the user to ClearAll tabs. Right now the clear button only clears what's on the currently selected tab, and leaves everything else alone.  My thought on how to do this was to iterate through the tabitems with this loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            tabSelection.SelectedIndex = i;
            clearButton_Click(null, null);
        }
```

It will flip through all the tabs, but won't clear anything.  I have tried using Automation instead, with the same result.  It just won't seem to clear anything.

**ChildControls class:**

```
class ChildControls
{
private List<object> listChildren;

public List<object> GetChildren(Visual p_vParent, int p_nLevel)
{
    if (p_vParent == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Element {0} is null!", p_vParent.ToString());
    }

    this.listChildren = new List<object>();

    this.GetChildControls(p_vParent, p_nLevel);

    return this.listChildren;

}

private void GetChildControls(Visual p_vParent, int p_nLevel)
{
    int nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(p_vParent);

    for (int i = 0; i <= nChildCount - 1; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(p_vParent, i);

        listChildren.Add((object)v);

        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(v) > 0)
        {
            GetChildControls(v, p_nLevel + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think this has to do with WPF behavior with TabControl.  I've read that when a tab goes out of view, the previous tab's visual tree gets "trashed".  You may want to abstract the Clear() to a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your code working you need to add the following line to your cleanup method:

```
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = i;
-->        UpdateLayout();
        Button_Click(null, null);
```

The UpdateLayout method takes care that the TabItem is drawn and the VisualTree is available afterwards.

Generally this approach isn't nice and if you have a real Application with Business data behind I'd recommend you have a look at databinding/MVVM. The approach shouldn't be to reset your controls in the view, but to reset your bound business data in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've been trying to understand MVVM more, but not sure where to begin.  Could you recommend any guides/books for starting out with it?

Comment: You're welcome. Just search here on SO and you find dozens of recommendations ..
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MVVM+tutorial

Comment: Been struggling with this for a day now, finally found the solution thanks to this. Winforms was so easy in comparison with wpf when you want to find a control!

Answer (score 4):

WPF discards the entire `VisualTree` of a `TabItem` which isn't selected, so no controls actually exist on tabs that are not visible.

To maintain control values (such as Selections, Text, etc), they need to be bound to something. If they're bound to something then your `Clear()` method should actually clear the Bound values, not the UI values. If they're not bound to anything, then the `TabControl` will revert to its initial state when selected.

Comment: I marked SvenG's comment as the answer because it did work in this situation.  I voted yours up though because it made me start to actually understand how MVVM works, and to see how much easier it would be.  I'm thinking my next major project on this is going to be converting what I have over to MVVM.